# How to use SASS to select a parent of a parent?

Tags: sass

I'm writing a cover that needs to be click-thru on the home page of my site.

```
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

My SCSS file looks like this.

```
body {
    #main {
        position: absolute;

        &#home & {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is styles like ...

```
body {
}
body #main {
    position: absolute;
}
body#home #main {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

What I get instead is

```
  body #main {
    position: absolute; }

    body #main#home body #main {
      pointer-events: none; }
```

How do I apply a condition on the parent of a parent?

Answer (score 0):

The `&` makes the styles go together on the same level (i.e. #main#home problem). Try this.

```
body {
  #main {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #home #main {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```